# How to fake write-protected script's $0 (zeroth arg) to be a path where I have no write-access?

Tags: scripting, shebang

It's said relying on $0 in a script is dangerous (often citing to fake it: exec -a ...).
Yes, in dirs where I have write-access I can symlink to a script to fake its $0.
But how to make $0 point to a path where I have no write-access (such as /bin/pwd below)?

Below, provided my script uses a shebang, I cannot achieve it. Can it be done when target script uses a shebang?

```
$ (exec -a /bin/pwd /tmp/a0.sh)
no-shebang: argv0=/bin/pwd /proc/.../cmdline=/bin/bash^@--noediting^@-i^@

$ (exec -a /bin/pwd /tmp/a1.sh)
yes-shebang: argv0=/tmp/a1.sh /proc/.../cmdline=/bin/sh^@/tmp/a1.sh^@

$ head /tmp/a0.sh /tmp/a1.sh
==> /tmp/a0.sh <==
echo no-shebang: argv0="$0" /proc/.../cmdline=$(cat -v /proc/$$/cmdline)

==> /tmp/a1.sh <==
#!/bin/sh
echo yes-shebang: argv0="$0" /proc/.../cmdline=$(cat -v /proc/$$/cmdline)
```

That is, if a script (& its parent-dirs) are write-protected, AND uses a shebang, then its use of $0 is safe (from faking another write-protected path)?

Here using (on centos 7) bash's exec statement as easy fake of $0. C program using execve() won't be different?
Is the failure to fake it downstream of the execve() (in kernel or shebang-target), not that bash's exec is too weak?

EDIT: execve() in C also does NOT fake the $0 in shebang case, same output as above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  char* argv[] = { "/bin/pwd", NULL };
  execve("/tmp/a1.sh", argv, NULL);
  perror(NULL);
}
```

I'm aware if users gain root, then fake $0 is least of your issues.
But MY write-protected scripts, with shebang, cannot be $0 faked (to another write-protected path), by non-root users: the danger of $0 ('just use exec -a ...') seems false.

Comment: A simple C program and the `execve` system call will let you set `argv[0]` (where `$0` comes from) to anything you like. `man execve` or https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve

Comment: Use `sudo cp` to copy your executable to a directory, like `/usr/local/bin/` that you (as `$USER`) don't have write access to. Remember to `sudo rm` your executable at the end of testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [the `execve(2)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) says:

> **Interpreter scripts**
>
> An interpreter script is a text file that has
> execute permission    enabled and whose first line is of the form:
>
> ```
> #!interpreter [optional-arg]
> ```
>
> The interpreter must be a valid pathname for an executable file.
>
> If the pathname argument of execve() specifies an interpreter
> script, then interpreter will be invoked with the following
> arguments:
>
> ```
> interpreter [optional-arg] pathname arg...
> ```

So, when you run `exec -a /bin/pwd /tmp/a1.sh`, the system runs `/bin/sh /tmp/a1.sh`, and when started like that, the shell sets `$0` from the name of the script file.

The value the shell gets in `argv[0]` doesn't come to it, e.g. `exec -a foobar /bin/sh /tmp/a1.sh` would still show `/tmp/a1.sh` in `$0`, and from the contents of `/proc/.../cmdline`, it looks like the value set when running the script gets lost anyway.

But it doesn't mean the value the script sees in `$0` could not be faked: a user can make a symlink to the script and call it through the link, or do something like:

```
/bin/sh -c ". /tmp/a1.sh" foobar
```

that would set `$0` to `foobar`, then simply source into `/tmp/a1.sh`.

Comment: As I said symlink doesn't give power to fake it to another write-protected path (where you have write-access [with or without root] you can make a script to do anything you want). But the source... form:  that does it exactly, works to fake it to  /bin/pwd without root or write-access to /bin! (And "just use exec -a" or power of execve() doesn't enter into it).